# Max volume of a cone in a sphere

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

I have given to compute the maximum volume of a cone inscribed in a sphere of radius $R>0$.

My question is give that x-radius of the cone the formula to maximize is
$\frac{1}{3} \pi (R^2-x^2)(R+x)$ or $\frac{1}{3} \pi x^2 \times \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the radius of the cone is $x\leq R$ then the distance of the base of the cone from the center of the sphere is given by $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ and the height of the cone is $R+\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$. If we set $x=R\sin\theta$, we have to maximize:

$$ V = \frac{\pi}{3} x^2\left(R+\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\right) = \frac{\pi R^3}{3}\sin^2\theta\,(1+\cos\theta) $$
or, by setting $y=\cos\theta$, 
$$ V = \frac{\pi R^3}{3}(1-y^2)(1+y). $$
Since $\frac{d}{dy}(1+y)(1-y^2)=(1+y)(1-3y)$, the maximum is achieved at $y=\frac{1}{3}$ and it is:
$$ V = \frac{32}{81}\pi R^3.$$

Comment: Can you say an argument for why the cone with maximum volume should have its "peak" at the top of the sphere? i.e why this should be right circular cone and not oblique circular cone

Comment: If the cone is oblique, with the same base you have an inferior height, hence an inferior volume.